# Default DOCTYPE breaks table - used on default Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, plugins, doctype

I am trying to make a plugin for WordPress.

It works great, except when i load the default WordPress themes. e.g. "twentyeleven."

This theme has a DOCTYPE as shown below. And hence, no matter what I do, it always inserts this annoying GAP when i put an image in a table.

**Please Help!
How do I get rid of this gap?**

Below is some code. Anytime a table is placed in a situation in which the DOCTYPE is defined as it is here, then I get this gap.

The WordPress default themes seem to use this DOCTYPE declaration. So they BREAK my pretty plugins...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>

<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%">
            <img border="0" src="http://goo.gl/PJdRU">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

All browsers render the above code as shown below. I just want to REMOVE the Gap! Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions, but neither is perfect. I guess the easiest will be just change your img's style - in CSS (with `td img { display: block }` rule) or just an inline style, like this:

```
<img style="display:block" border="0" src="http://goo.gl/PJdRU">
```

Here's [an article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps) with explanations why you see what you see - and several possible ways of fixing it. ) And here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2V2QT/) to play with.